# Conditional Cascade Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I'm trying to find an elegant solution for one problem that I have.

So I have this application that has a DBContext, a UoW and several Repos.
The DBContext in the constructor only accepts a connection string, then it has a method that returns a IDBConnection, based on an input that will do a switch (SqlLite, Sql, etc.) to create the correct connection.
The UoW and the Repos, will be injected with the IDBConnection that will be served by the DBContext method.

So at boot of the application I need somehow to instantiate the DBContext (singleton) with the correct connection string.

Then because the UoW and the Repos shouldn't know anything about each other, they all must receive the same IDBConnection and in the correct order...

So the UoW will be the first, because it has the responsibility to open and initialize a transaction over the connection, and the Repos will receive the same connection, that's already open and ready to use to perform their job.

I could put the repos "under" the uow, but I'm trying to see if there's another way to do this?
Suggestions needed.

Btw: I'm not using EF or anything, just plain SQL and maybe I'll use Dapper later on.

Thanks

*EDIT*
Just sample code:

```cs
//Main ...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var context = new DBContext(@"Data Source=..."); 

var dbConnection = context.GetConnection(Models.ConnectionType.SqlLite);

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUow, Uow>(x => new Uow(dbConnection));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepoAaa, RepoAaa>(x => new RepoAaa(dbConnection));


//SAMPLE CONTEXT
public class DBContext : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DBContext(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    //... other code
    public IDbConnection GetConnection(ConnectionType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ConnectionType.SqlLite:
                return new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
            case ConnectionType.SqlServer:
                return new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Connection type unrecognized");
        }
    }
}

//SAMPLE UOW
public class Uow : IUow
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;
    private readonly IDbTransaction _dbTransaction;
    private bool _disposedValue;

    public Uow(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _dbConnection = dbConnection;
        _dbConnection.Open();
        _dbTransaction = _dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    //... other code
}


//SAMPLE REPO
public class RepoAaa : IRepoAaa, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;
    private bool _disposedValue;

    public RepoAaa(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question and show concrete examples of your design? Please provide the least amount of code that demonstrates your design and the problem you are facing.

Comment: Starting transactions inside of constructors might not be the best approach, because it makes object construction unreliable and causes the order in which objects get created influence the correct behavior of your application. A better approach might be to use decorators to control transactions in a timely manner. For instance, take a look at [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/commands/) for inspiration on how to design your application in a way that allows this.